# Boundary conditions for the stagnation point axisymmetric boundary layer equations

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, simulations, boundary-conditions

Good morning,
I am trying to solve the Boundary Layer equations in the stagnation point in order to compute the stagnation point heat flux. In particular, the fluid is:

-A continuum

-In thermal and chemical equilibrium

-Steady flow

-The flow outside the boundary layer is inviscid, and there are no heat transfers

-The only heat transfer is inside the boundary layer, on the stagnation point of an axisymmetric body, following the Fourier law:
$\vec{q}=-\lambda_{eq} \nabla{T}$

-I am considering only the stagnation streamline, which is isentropic outside the boundary layer for the hypotheses made.

The equations are the following:

[image: Axisymmetric boundary layer equations]

The problem is that I need to supply these equations with the appropriate boundary conditions. On the wall:

-T=Tw: wall temperature, constant by hypothesis

-u=0: no-slip condition

-P=Pe

On the edge:

-T=Te

-u=ue

-P=Pe

The pressure is the same for wall and edge because from the hypotheses, $\frac{dP}{dy}=0$

Now, my idea would be to use the stagnation pressure and stagnation temperature as edge conditions, so Pe=Ptot, Te=Ttot,since that we are close to the stagnation point (and if dP/dy=0, and we have Ptot in the stagnation point, we need to have Ptot on the edge), and this is what it is done is some article I read, with u=velocity of the edge.

But what I do not understand, it is that if we have total conditions, by definition we should have u=0, since that the total conditions are obtained by an isentropic deceleration of the flow to u=0.

So, how is it possible that we have the total conditions, but u!=0 ?

But if T=Ttot when u=0, so on the wall, this does not make a lot of sense either, since that we need to have T=Tw on the wall.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.